# Can methods be added to an object?

Tags: c++

So we have a class, `Customer`. I don't have any choice but to use `Customer` to represent any Customer I have, including in the signature of any methods, etc I write. But my data is slightly different; I still want much of the functionality inside `Customer`, but some fields I need to sorta bastardize for my special case. Example:

```
class Customer
{
public:
  string GetName();
  void SetName(string _name);

  string GetAge();
  void SetAge(string _age);

protected:
  string name;
  string age;
};

class SpecialCustomer : public Customer
{
public:
  string GetAddress();
  void SetAddress(string _address);
}
```

So this all seems rather simple, but the problem I have is I am forced to pass around `Customer`s. But as luck would  have it, in my special case, I don't need `age` at all! So what I need to do is re-use the `age` data member to hold my address. Yes, I know it's bad. No, I can't change the requirements - my special data *has* to fit into a `Customer` object.

So to do this, I could of course just construct a `SpecialCustomer` from a `Customer`, but I'd like to avoid the copy. (edit: Also, many data members are exposed directly publicly, so I can't use composition and support their use) Instead, I considered making `SpecialCustomer` a wrapper, exposing the pieces of functionality I want. The problem is the real implementation of `Customer` is not trivial - it's be a bit of work to re-implement the whole interface, minus the fields I don't want.

The only way that jumps to mind to achieve this is with something like this:

```
void foo (Customer & _c)
{
  SpecialCustomer & sc = reinterpret_cast<SpecialCustomer &>(_c);
}
```

Obviously if `SpecialCustomer` has any virtual methods or data members, this won't work. But what if it is just a set of methods I want available on the object? Is there a better alternative to achieve this functionality?

Comment: i guess i don't follow. why isn't having `GetAddress() { return age; }` adequate?

Comment: methods can certainly be added to a class. More difficult to add them to an object

Comment: @adequate I can't copy the object, and I'm given a `Customer`, not a `SpecialCustomer` @TinyTheBrontosaurus Indeed, hence the question :) Note I did mention composition, and why I can't do it!

Comment: Ahh, i get it.  I think the wrapper you want is not using inheritance, but rather composition. I'll write an answer...

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` is invalid unless `Customer` already is a `SpecialCustomer`. You are hoping that casting to a derived class with no extra data members should be valid, but the standard doesn't mention any such special rule.

Comment: does `Customer` have any virtual methods? If not, i can think of a way that will often work even though it doesn't agree with the standard

Comment: @BoPersson That's relevant to my question - is this behavior defined in the standard? Also, I don't know what you mean by 'invalid' - it actually works if you care to try it :) (https://paste.ofcode.org/xNezz6fdrCqzeeXDLfHY9P)

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus It does

Comment: @Rollie - The cast is telling the compiler that the object that `_c` is a reference to really is a `SpecialCustomer`. If it is not, the result will be undefined. Seeming to work is one possible effect of undefined behavior. In this case not even very surprising, but still undefined.

Comment: If I knew it was a `SpecialCustomer`, I could use `dynamic_cast` - I think this kind of scenario is when you *do* use `reinterpret_cast`. So in this case, inside `SpecialCustomer::GetAddress()`, the `this` pointer is definitely pointing to the `Customer` object, right? So when I call `return age` it's the same as `return this->age`. I suspect the compiler will treat this as `return dynamic_cast<Customer *>(this)->age;`, so the only chance of this failing is if the `this` pointer is being offset to get at `age` (true for multiple inheritance cases perhaps). So this feels like it may always work

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your hands are tied from using OO techniques. How about using plain old non-member functions of the form

```
string getSpecialCustomerAddress (Customer & _c)
{
  return _c.GetAge();
}
```

You still have the problem of determining whether or not a customer is special

Comment: I think this is most likely the case. I am still curious if my proposed solution is actually viable, or if there's a convincing reason that won't work.

Comment: What is the difference from my proposed solution that you lowered but this you love? The only thing that I additionally proposed to replace GetAge values with empties, but I did not force you to apply whole solution and change GetAge.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it, using composition instead of inheritance.

```
class SpecialCustomer {
public:
    SpecialCustomer(Customer&) : _customer(customer) {}

    string getAge() { return customer.GetAge(); }

private:
    Customer& _customer;

}
```

No casting is needed at this point. Rather instantiating the wrapper class will be adequate.

Usage:

```
void foo (Customer & _c)
{
    SpecialCustomer sc(_c);
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a good solution, but I need the `SpecialCustomer` to have all the functionality of the original `Customer`, including use of public data members. Also, as mentioned, the *real* implementation of this is rather complicated, so I'm not keen on trying to do this. Also, if I did, it would make maintenance of future methods added to `Customer` more difficult.

Comment: I think it has to reference `_c`; if I do `SetAddress()` I need it to change the original object, unless I copy back to that before returning from the function, which I don't love because it feels easy to forget.